# Next div, previous div navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do a next/previous div navigation. I have searched a lot on Google but couldn't find exactly what I need.

First of all, I want to keep my html structure intact

```
<html>
<body>
<a name="1"></a>
<div class="section">Blah blah</div>
<a name="2"></a>
<div class="section">Blah blah</div>
<a name="3"></a>
<div class="section">Blah blah</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This means no to adding wrappers or anything of the sort.

What I want from the navigation system is the following:

2 links/buttons triggering the scrolling to the appropriate `<a>` tag.

I want the navigation to have `position: fixed;` so it will stay in a place I need it while scrolling.

Lastly, the thing I couldn't find is for it to detect the current location based on what the navigation buttons superpose.

This means if I press next while the buttons are below `<a name="2"></a>` but above `<a name="3"></a>`, it will scroll down to `<a name="3"></a>`

Comment: Your `</a>` syntax is wrong. You have `<` at the end of it instead of `>`.

Comment: Put the current DIV name in a variable. Then use jQuery's DOM navigation methods like `.next()` and `.prev()` to find the DIV you want to go to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a data attribute to the button element to indicate the current position, and then read the last attribute back when the button is clicked. I'm on my phone so I can't test the code that follows,  but hopefully it will get you started.

```
<a id="next" data-current="1">》</a>
<a id="prev">《</a>

function getCurrent () {
  return parseInt($("#next").attr ("data-current").val ());
}

function setCurrent(idx) {
  $("#next").attr("current", idx);
}

$("#next").on ("click", function () {
  val idx = getCurrent() + 1;
  if (idx > 3) idx = 1;
  navigateTo(idx);
  setCurrent (idx);
});

 // do the same for previous,  if (idx < 1) idx = 3;
```

Comment: For whatever reason it doesn't seem to work, I went through the code a few times but can't see the issue. Could you possibly build a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm on my phone, no fiddle. Lookup how to set custom attributes with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

first you need can add id in your elements and you can use the class and navigate on prev and next.

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <a name="1"></a>
 <div class="section">Blah blah</div>
 <a name="2"></a>
 <div class="section">Blah blah</div>
 <a name="3"></a>
 <div class="section">Blah blah</div>
 </body>
 </html>

 $(a).click(function(){
 if($(this).attr('name') == "3"){
    $(this).prev().click();
   } 
 })
```

Note: this is an example how to navigate next and prev values.